# find id of tr in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had table indatalist and I had to find id of tr in table I did my code but error apeared (object refrence...).

aspx:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onitemdatabound="DataList2_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

                    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                        <tr id="AllText" runat="server">
                            <td class="media_ved_tit_aro" id="AllArrow" runat="server">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td class="media_txt_b " >
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval(Globals.Translate("YoutubeTitle_EN", Page))%>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

cs:

```
protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    string LanguageID = Globals.GetSuitableLanguage(Page);
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
       {
           ArrowAll  = e.Item.FindControl("AllArrow") as HtmlGenericControl;
           TextAll = e.Item.FindControl("AllText") as HtmlGenericControl;
       }
       if (LanguageID == "ar")
       {

           ArrowAll.Attributes.Add("Class", "media_ved_tit_aro_AR");
           TextAll.Attributes.Add("Class", "News_Image");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tr, td does not get mapped to HtmlGenericControl but rather to `HtmlTableRow` and `HtmlTableCell`. I would prefer a cast to base control - `HtmlControl`. In short, change below code fragment as shown:

```
ArrowAll = e.Item.FindControl("AllArrow") as HtmlControl; 
TextAll = e.Item.FindControl("AllText") as HtmlControl;
```